# Run each for a class but once for group

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a lot of elements with the same class. These elements are divided into groups by means of attribute "**data-xxx**"

```
<div class="myclass" data-n="group1"></div>
<div class="myclass" data-n="group1"></div>
<div class="myclass" data-n="group1"></div>
.... 
<div class="myclass" data-n="group2"></div>
<div class="myclass" data-n="group2"></div>
...
<div class="myclass" data-n="group3"></div>
...
...
```

How to perform a function on each item, but only once in each group using something like this?

```
$('.myclass').each(function(){

/// My function

});
```

Comment: I don't think jquery has a selector that accounts for data properties.

Comment: @DanMayor - Sure you can: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/nzgyT/

Comment: @DanMayor  selector used is also irrelevant to the issue

Comment: @FrançoisWahl is right. It's either once per group or once per member of the class. Sure you can have other rules, but you would need (a) to define the rules very precisely and (b) to ensure the elements have classes and/or attributes to make the rules implementable.

Comment: should explain your needs in more detail...  there are different ways to interpret this

Comment: Thanks a lot! Once again, this helped me with the decision a difficult task for me, very fast and very true!
Once again bow to all! )))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5sKqU/1/**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var group = {}; //an object that we're going to use as a hash  
    $('.myclass').each(function(){ 
        if (group[$(this).attr('data-n')] != true) {
            group[$(this).attr('data-n')] = true;

            //do something here once per each group
            alert('Group: '+ $(this).attr('data-n'));
        }
    }); 
});
```

I'm assuming that you only need this to run once on page load. If you could share more about your requirements, I can show you what changes you'll need to make.

Comment: +1 though I probably would have used [an array](http://jsfiddle.net/5sKqU/2/). ;p

Comment: This decision was the most striking and elegant in my opinion! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe :

```
var groups = {};
$('.myclass').each(function(i, el) {
    var n = $(el).data('n');
    if(!groups[n]) {
        groups[n] = $();
    }
    groups[n] = groups[n].add(el);
});

//At this point the object `groups` has one property per group, 
//each value being a jquery collection comprising members of the group.

//Now the world's your oyster. You can loop through the groups 
//with full access to each group's members if necessary.
$.each(groups, function(groupName, jq) {
    //my function
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a certain HTML attribute on all group elements after processing the first one. After that, you can check the value of that attribute:

```
$('.myclass').each(function(){

  if($(this).attr("processed")!="true") {
      // process...
      $("[data-n=" + $(this).attr("data-n")).attr("processed", "true");
  } else {
     // skip, or do something else with the element
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select out each group with the jQuery attribute selector, like this:

```
$( '.myclass[data-n="groupX"]' );
```

I'm not sure if you meant that you only wanted to apply your function to one element in each group, but if so this will give you only the first in each:

```
$( '.myclass[data-n="groupX"]' ).first();
```

Given that you label your groups 1 through N you can just check if there is anything in the resulting set to determine when you have looped through every group.

Comment: remove space from selector